# How do you go backwards through a chain using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I thought there was something in jquery that allowed you go backward through a chain.

I want to do this:

```
var a = $(this).parent().addClass('test').goBackToParent().children('selectorHere').text()
```

I want to get the parent of the object that I have and add a class name to it. Once I do that I want to go through its children and find a child that matches my selector and get its text.

Can I do this, or do I have to do this instead:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('test');
var a = $(this).parent().children('selectorHere').text()
```

**Edit**

I am using "end" now but it does not work I made an example that you can try  [here](http://jsbin.com/uzocu4/2)

```
<table>
    <th>
        <tr>one</tr>
        <tr>two</tr>
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td id="test"><a href="#"><img src="http://ais.web.cern.ch/ais/apps/hrt/SMT%20v2/Images/btnbar_edit.png" /></a></td>
        <td class="selectMe">1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        // does not work
        var a = $(this).parent().addClass('afb')
                   .end().children('.selectMe').text();

        // works
        var b = $(this).parent().children('.selectMe').text();

        alert(a + ' -should have value');
        alert(b + ' -works');

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're looking for the [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) method:

```
var a = $(this).parent().addClass('test').end()
               .children('selectorHere').text();
```

The method:

> Ends the most recent filtering
>   operation in the current chain and
>   returns the set of matched elements to
>   its previous state.

**Update**: based on your html snippet, you actually don't need `end` at all!  The important thing about jQuery, is that most non-traversal methods return a copy of themselves - so if you call $(this).addClass('test'), you get a copy of $(this) back.

So for your snippet:

```
// does not work
var a = $(this)                       // points at #test
           .parent()                  // now refers to the tr which holds test
               .addClass('afb')       // still refers to the tr
               .end()                 // now we're back to #test
           .children('.selectMe')     // empty! there are no direct children of #test which match .selectMe
               .text();               // empty
```

Instead, try it without the end:

```
// works
var a = $(this)                       // points at #test
           .parent()                  // now refers to the tr which holds test
               .addClass('afb')       // still refers to the tr
           .children('.selectMe')     // found the .selectMe td
               .text();               // returns '1'
```

Comment: Weird when I do this I don't get a value for text anymore. If I get ride of addClass and end I do.

Comment: It'd help if you could post an html snippet so we know exactly what you're trying to manipulate.  Based on your comment, it sounds like the 'selectorHere' element is actually a direct child of the parent (i.e. a sibling or $(this)), rather than a child of $(this)

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for the method [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/). Just use it in place of `goBackToParent()`.

> Most of jQuery's DOM traversal methods
>   operate on a jQuery object instance
>   and produce a new one, matching a
>   different set of DOM elements. When
>   this happens, it is as if the new set
>   of elements is pushed onto a stack
>   that is maintained inside the object.
>   Each successive filtering method
>   pushes a new element set onto the
>   stack. If we need an older element
>   set, we can use end() to pop the sets
>   back off of the stack.

Answer (score 5):

See [.`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)